# невидимые символы

Tags: unicode

на сайтах есть ссылки вида `example.com` но в конце стоит несколько непечатаемых символов, например:

```
$s = '­example.com﻿';
print_r(count_chars($s, 1));

$s = my_text_to_line1($s);//тут эти символы вырезаются
print_r(count_chars($s, 1));

//result
Array
(
  [46] => 1
  [97] => 1
  [99] => 1
  [101] => 2
  [108] => 1
  [109] => 2
  [111] => 1
  [112] => 1
  [120] => 1
  [173] => 1
  [187] => 1
  [191] => 1
  [194] => 1
  [239] => 1
)
Array
(
  [46] => 1
  [97] => 1
  [99] => 1
  [101] => 2
  [108] => 1
  [109] => 2
  [111] => 1
  [112] => 1
  [120] => 1
)
```

у меня пара вопросов:
  1. сколько всего таких вариантов и можно ли их как-то все отловить без метода перебора?
  2. что это за символы, может из другой кодировки?

Comment: Вы посчитали не символы, а байты. Если считать символы, то «лишних» в вашем примере всего два: в начале [мягкий перенос](https://unicode-table.com/ru/00AD/), в конце [маркер последовательности байтов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) (хотя вообще-то маркеру положено стоять наоборот в начале)

Comment: такой вариант удаления не нужных символов из домена подходит? ```([[:cntrl:]]|[^[:graph:]])```